# VSomeip 1 clien and 2 hosts

Tags: vsomeip

I Have the following configuration: a linux with 2 eth interfaces, and 2 external devices.
The ip for one external device is 192.168.10.1 and my eth0 ip is 192.168.10.2(communication works), the 2nd device ip is 192.168.20.1 and my eth1 is 192.168.20.2(here works too). The external devices are vsomeip services and I try to connect to booth of them(only 1 works). Is there any configuration that I can do so I can have all the services working in one app? So far I tried to add booth my ip addresses in client.json:

```
  "unicast" : "192.168.10.2",
  "unicast" : "192.168.20.2",
```